# Paypal automatic return URL feature

Tags: paypal

What we noticed in testing is the PayPal return url works for payments made via the PayPal account just fine.

However, if one chooses to pay using the PayPal system to pay via credit card and they do not have an account there is an intermediate step that requires one to "click a button" to return to our "return URL".

Our processing is set up to do some work when going to the return URL page and getting the PDT is a trigger.

My fear is if a client does not click that intermediate link that says "return to xx xxx company" the processing and receipt of the PDT will not occur and that is not a good thing.

Anyone else having this issue and is there a workaround I have not found yet?  Not sure why PayPal does this to us in those circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, `Auto Return` feature will work only in `Pay with PayPal` option and not with Credit card. As a work around, you can use Instant Payment Notification([IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)) which does not depend on whether the users  click on "Return" link, since IPN is asynchronous and will send your server notification whenever the transaction is complete.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for confirming.